# css3 circle glow like a Moon light glow

Tags: html, css

i am trying to create a moon with light glow. same as in images.

i have tried but not much successful.

I don't wants to use image in website. i wants to create only this with CSS3.

**My circle is creating very small and also glow is in small area . i want glow in large radius area**

http://jsfiddle.net/naresh_kumar/ezUfG/6/

[image]

**Html**

```
<div>
    <span>Glow</span>
</div>
```

**Css**

```
div {
    margin: 20px 10px 10px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

span {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-top: 40px;
    background: whiteSmoke;
    width: 100px;
    height: 60px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;

    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #F8A50E;
       -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #F8A50E;
            box-shadow: 0 0 10px #F8A50E;

    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
       -moz-border-radius: 50px;
            border-radius: 50px;

    -webkit-transition: box-shadow .4s ease;
       -moz-transition: box-shadow .4s ease;
        -ms-transition: box-shadow .4s ease;
         -o-transition: box-shadow .4s ease;
            transition: box-shadow .4s ease;
}

span:hover {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px red;
       -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px red;
            box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px red;
}
```

Comment: I don't know what you're doing with your HTML there. Please separate your CSS from your HTML.

Comment: Also, I think you can safely ommit the `-moz` prefix for box-shadow ([support table](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-boxshadow)) and the `-moz`, `-ms` and `-o` prefixes on transitions. ([support table](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions)). **edit:** border-radius does no more need prefixing at all. ;)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

use `box-shadow` :)

This example uses two comma separated shadows:

```
  box-shadow:0 0 50px gold,0 0 150px gold;
```

http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/qdcos

You could draw it with radial-gradient too.
Result will varie from browser to browser.

Comment: k thanx. could you please guide me for this problem more clearly. ?

Comment: Your shadow needs to be bigger, and to reinforce it, you need to use multiple shadows so it does not fade away too fast. on this exemple, the 2 shadows overlap the first 50px. You can even increase the effet with a fourth parameter box-shadow:0 0 50px  10px gold,0 0 150px  10px gold; the firs 10 px of the shadow will have a very high opacity (close to 1)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this style for your `box-shadow`:

```
box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px red;
```

Try this:

```
box-shadow: 0 0 10px red;
```

**Edit:** If you want the glow to be bigger, just increase the radius:

```
box-shadow: 0 0 30px red;
```

[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/ezUfG/9/)

Comment: My circle is creating very small and also glow is in small area . i want glow in large radius area...

And sir where is the update.

Comment: Update made, just click where it says *jsFiddle here*

Comment: your link creating this link http://jsfiddle.net/ezUfG/9/
is this your ??? and there is no any update.

Comment: It is an update of your fiddle. My answer explains how to solve your question and the link is an example of my explanation.

Comment: That's not 'too many parameters,' `box-shadow` can take four numeric parameters and the colour. The fourth number gives a 'non-fading spread' (which is the best way I can describe it, despite being an entirely made-up definition).

Comment: @F4r-20  k sir thnx . i got it.

But my problem was different.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you want:

```
span:hover {
    -webkit-border-radius: 70px;
    -moz-border-radius: 70px;
    border-radius: 70px;   
    -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 10px red;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px red;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px red;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ezUfG/10/